# How can I write data from a pickle file to sqlite3 database?

Tags: python, sqlite, pickle

I have webscraped data into a pickle file and want to write that data into a sqlite3 database. Can anybody help me out with what needs to be done?

Comment: Um, what *exactly* do you want to do?

Comment: are you sure you want this anyway? Why store a blob of data in a data store that is meant to store structured data?

Comment: I have data from a recipe website and want to store it in sqlite3 for easy retrieval. We've stored the data in a pkl file, but I'm not sure how the data can be interfaced with a database.

Comment: Why not use [`shelve`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shelve.html)? It uses `pickle` to store data.

Comment: I've never used it before. Could you please help me understand how it can be used in this scenario?

Comment: If you want "easy retrieval" it seems odd to store it as a pickle. You appear to be using sqlite as if it was some kind of archive (like a zip file), and not using any of its most powerful features.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a column of type `BLOB` (which is a [supported datatype](https://sqlite.org/datatype3.html) in Sqlite3).

Then, you can just `INSERT INTO data (id, content) VALUES (?, ?)` with the binary dump of your pickle object.

Here's a [walk through on Sqlite3 inserts](http://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-insert/).

[`pickle.dumps`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html#pickle.dumps) will convert the object into a byte-string you can store in the database. [`pickle.loads`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html#pickle.loads) will turn it back after being `SELECT`'d from the database.

You can also consider using [`dill`](https://github.com/uqfoundation/dill) for more complex objects.

Comment: I did exactly how you have stated. However when querying from the database, pickle.loads gives EOFError Ran out of input. I checked loads just before inserting to database - it runs fine however after reading the inserted value, it feels. I have no idea why this is happening . Please help.